# Lighttpd vhost regex

Tags: virtualhost, lighttpd, regex

I'm having a problem with my vhosts using regex. When I use the following code, I get a 404 not found:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)example\.com$" {
...
}
```

However, when I explicitly set it to the following, I can get to my site:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "example.com" {
...
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? The documentation is fairly sparse.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found my problem. I'm using port 8080 instead of port 80 and I read the somewhat hidden text on the very bottom of the [documentation page](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModSimpleVhost) that states:

> (Doesn't work for you? If you're not running on the default port,
>   $HTTP["host"] will have the port number appended and the above reg-ex
>   won't match it, since the trailing "$" means
>   "the-string-ends-this-way".)

Answer (score 1):

You already found the problem; now fix it by using `($|:)` or `(:[0-9]+)?$` instead of `$`.